# Как работает replace в Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Я пока только начал изучать Котлин и работу с анонимными функциями в частности, поэтому возможно мой вопрос покажется дурацким, но тем не менее:

В учебнике по Котлин есть такой пример применения функции replace

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    var frase = "hello"
    var frase3 = toReplace(frase)
    println(frase3)
}

fun toReplace(frase:String)
        = frase.replace(Regex("[lo]"))
{
    println(it)
    println(it.value)
    when(it.value) {
        "l" -> "1"
        "o"-> "0"
        else -> " "
    }
}
```

но если смотреть реализацию метода replace в String.kt, то я вижу только две сигнатуры:

```
public inline fun CharSequence.replace(regex: Regex, replacement: String): String =
regex.replace(this, replacement)
            
public inline fun CharSequence.replace(regex: Regex, noinline transform: (MatchResult) -> CharSequence): String =
regex.replace(this, transform)
```

и обе из них принимают по два параметра:

1. Regex
2. String или Функция

В приведенном же мной примере анонимная функция вынесена за пределы скобок, т.е. передается не как параметр, а выполняется как часть ф-ции toReplace.
Как это работает?

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь стало ясно.

Answer (score 0):

> В приведенном же мной примере анонимная функция вынесена за пределы скобок, т.е. передается не как параметр, а выполняется как часть ф-ции toReplace.

- нет, лямбда за скобками - это последний параметр метода `replace`. Синтаксис Kotlin позволяет последний параметр, если он является лямбдой, выносить за круглые скобки (и вообще убирать круглые скобки, если лямбда - единственный параметр). По сути, `frase.replace(Regex("[lo]")) { ... }` это то же самое, что `frase.replace(Regex("[lo]"), { ... })`.

Выдержка из документации ([источник](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter)):

> #### Passing trailing lambdas
>
> According to Kotlin convention, if the last parameter of a function is
> a function, then a lambda expression passed as the corresponding
> argument can be placed outside the parentheses:
>
> ```kotlin
> val product = items.fold(1) { acc, e -> acc * e }
> ```
>
> Such syntax is also known as *trailing lambda*.
>
> If the lambda is the only argument in that call, the parentheses can
> be omitted entirely:
>
> ```kotlin
> run { println("...") }
> ```

Перевод ([источник](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas)):

> #### Передача лямбды в качестве последнего параметра
>
> В Kotlin существует соглашение: если последний параметр функции
> является функцией, то лямбда-выражение, переданное в качестве
> соответствующего аргумента, может быть вынесено за круглые скобки.
>
> ```kotlin
> val product = items.fold(1) { acc, e -> acc * e }
> ```
>
> Такой синтаксис также известен как *trailing lambda*.
>
> Когда лямбда-выражение является единственным аргументом функции,
> круглые скобки могут быть опущены.
>
> ```kotlin
> run { println("...") }
> ```